# Android OpenGLRenderer "Dirty" error

Tags: android, opengl-es, wear-os

While programming an Android wear application I ran into the following log message(Well, 15 of them in a row):

... W/OpenGLRenderer: Dirty 145.00 306.00 175.00 320.00 doesn't intersect with 0 0 320 290 ?

(The question mark is part of the log message)

I am not explicitly using OpenGl in my application, this error is generated when a fragment with an animated custom view is swiped to in a GridViewPager. Whether or not this appears depends on the device, this does not occur on an Android emulator, but on a Moto360 (The only test device I have access to). Also the warning/error is accompanied by some lag.

As for the question: Any idea what the numbers are or what they mean, and what exactly is "Dirty". Any tips, pointers to documentation, or advice is greatly appreciated.